# Ubuntu 17.10 cannot detect bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth, 17.10

I wanted to connect my dualshock 4 to computer. Everything was ok, I connected it, but had some problems with its functionality. So, I downloaded `ds4drv` and connected DualShock to computer using this ds4drv. It worked fine and I've been playing games for an hour-two. After that I rebooted computer and tried to connect it again, but bluetooth didn't detect device. Moreover, it still doesn't detect **any** device, not just dualshock. What did I wrong and how to fix it?